# Remove line-breaks and spaces from textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, line-breaks, spaces

```
<textarea rows='5' cols='50' id='content'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='Extract Text' onclick='someFunction()'/>
```

Assume these two html elements. My problem is the following:

Let's say that the user enters into the textarea field something like this, exactly as typed. With all line breaks and spaces. (And yes, this is Python :P)

```
if (...):  
   print "Hello everyone!"
else:
   print "Dudes help me out!"
```

My objective is to make a JavaScript function which removes all the spaces and line breaks (typed with 'Enter') and returns a space-less string. Something like "ThisIsASampleText". I've used `document.getElementById('content').value` and `myString.replace(/\s+/g, '')` to remove spaces. Can't make it work. Any ideas?

Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a live demo of how to use the regex you described to remove all whitespace in the text from your textarea:

```js
function someFunction() {
    var output = document.getElementById("content").value;
    output = output.replace(/\s/g, "") 
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows='5' cols='50' id='content'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='Extract Text' onclick='someFunction()'/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/afy5v66x/1/