# How to remove the blank lines in a textarea with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I get the content of a textarea with:

```
var stringArray = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
```

I must remove all blank lines (even blank lines with spaces). What is an efficient way to do that?

EDIT: I want to remove the blank lines, not the whitespace.

e.g.

```
A
  B

C

D
```

to

```
A
  B
C
D
```

Comment: Did you try anything, or are you just asking us to write code for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textarea - JavaScript | Remove line breaks and spaces from content field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039740/textarea-javascript-remove-line-breaks-and-spaces-from-content-field)

Comment: You're not forced to write code to help me. If you don't want to help find something else to do.

Comment: It is actually not a duplicate at least of the things mentioned by @skobaljic

Comment: Please guys, StackOverflow is not to help you or me, but everyone on the net. If the question is similar to other, than it should be marked as duplicate (it does not have to be completely same). At least it would help others to find their solution - please think globally.

Comment: And I thought this site is for helping programmers, especially the beginners...

Comment: Its not even that similar just because you can search and it comes up does not mean that it is the same... the example is about removing ALL white space which is infinitely easier that removing white space around letters in a row... Oh well google thought it was kinda similar so still counts as similar and lets down vote any one who answers a question that I personally think is broad. Sorry for trying to help I'm sure thats very encouraging to others.

Comment: @AceofHz This site is specifically for professional programmers, not beginners. Not sure where you got that impression.

Comment: @Juhana: Take a look at the About Me section: http://stackoverflow.com/company/about

"StackOverflow is the largest online community for programmers to learn, share their knowledge, and advance their careers".

It says programmers, not professional programmers. That includes the beginners and amateurs too. Too bad that exactly like Wikipedia, this site turned into an elitist forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it work. This is the code just in case someone else would need it:

```
function delBlankLines() {
 var stringArray = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split('\n');
 var temp = [""];
 var x = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
   if (stringArray[i].trim() != "") {
     temp[x] = stringArray[i];
     x++;
   }
 }

 temp = temp.join('\n');
 document.myform.textarea.value = temp;
}
```

So, the textarea content is split into a string array, that array is looped and checked if the trimmed current line is blank; if it's not, the line is copied to a temporary string array (basically the blank lines are ignored). At the end, I update the textarea with the temporary string array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the native JavaScript trim method (available on the string prototype): `textareaValue.trim()`.

Trivia: there's automatic setting of `window.textarea` to be `document.getElementById('textarea')`. So you can access that by just doing `textarea`. Therefore to access the textual content of the textarea you can use: `textarea.innerHTML` or `const textAreaValue = textarea.value`.

Next, run `textAreaValue.trim();` this will get rid of any outer white space. `"     \n\n textArea \n\n\t\n  "` will turn into just `"textArea"`.

Ok now we can split on new lines: `const stringArray = textAreaValue.split('\n')`. Since `\n` is the carriage return aka new line symbol.

Next, we'll want to skip any lines which have nothing but whitespace which we can probably find in a few ways but to be safest `\S` should work. To test out different regexes I recommend: regex101.com.

For a more modern version:

```js
textarea.value = `
  
    the
      quick
   brown
   fox
    jumped
      over the lazy
  dog.
  
  `;

/*
function oldSolution() {
  var cleanedString = '';
  console.log(textarea.value);
  var stringArray = textarea.value.trim().split('\n'); 
  for(var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    var line = stringArray[i];
    if(line.match('/\S/') !== -1){
      cleanedString += line.trim();
    }
  }
  console.log(cleanedString);
  output.innerText = cleanedString;
  return cleanedString;
}
*/
const cleanText = () => {
  const stringArray = textarea.value
    .trim()
    .split('\n')
    .filter(line => /\S/.test(line));
  console.log({stringArray})
  const cleanedString = stringArray.map(line => line.trim()).join(' ');
  console.log(cleanedString);
  output.innerText = cleanedString;
  return cleanedString;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows='5' cols='50' id='textarea'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='Extract Text' onclick='cleanText()'/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Whoever is giving minus points chill out I'm still working on the answer accidentally pressed save... christ this is why stack overflow is such a terrible place.

Comment: Trim removes whitespace from both sides of a string. But I want to preserve the whitespace on the lines with text and to remove it on the empty lines. I tried the splice() method but for some reason it doesn't work...

Comment: Just saying: I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Thanks for that I still am working but now its nearly done

Comment: Thanks Zargold for your effort. I thought about using Regex, but this thing is hell to get it right.